# SQL Query to compare two subsets from two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare all orders of type 728 to all of the other order types for each customer to find any customers where order types 728 have any items that are not in at least one other order type, or if any of the other order types have any items that are not in order type 728 for that customer.

```
    Customers
        OrderTypes
            Items

    Customer 2245
        OrderType 728
            Item PT
            Item Custom
            Item Special
        OrderType 234
            Item PT
            Item Custom
        OrderType 300
            Item PT
            Item Custom
        OrderType 999
            Item PT
```

I have queried so that I have a table variable of the order types of 728 (with Customer and order type data), @Items_728

I have queried so that I have a table variable of the order types of everything but 728 (with Customer and order type data), @Items_Not728

I want to get a resultset of all 728 order types per customer that have items not in other order types for that customer.

Example: OrderType 728 has an Item Special not found in at least one other OrderType

I want to get a resultset of all order types per customer that have items not in the 728 order type.

Example: OrderType 999 does not have Item Custom

I would like to do this as a set-based operation, rather than creating a cursor and walking it customer by customer, manually comparing sets of orders, noting any differences and saving each customer number. That seems terribly inefficient and dirty.

I have looked through other StackOverflow questions but have not noted anything that seemed to look like this. Any helpful suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your second example (999 doesnt have custom) doesnt seem to make sense in terms of the description. Can you clarify pls.

Answer (score 0):

result set #1: 728s with items not in other order types:

```
SELECT i.Cust, i.Item
FROM @Items_728 i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Items_Not728 WHERE Cust = i.Cust AND Item = i.Item)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

2nd required result set & example disagree, so not done.